# All MySQL processes hung when restoring multiple dump files

Tags: mysql

I have a Ruby program that uses a thread pool of 20 threads to download more than 1000 compressed MySQL dump files ("xxx.sql.gz"). After each file is downloaded, the script creates a database and calls

```
gzip -dc xxx.sql.gz | cat - commit.txt | mysql -D db_name
```

to restore the dump file.

commit.txt appends `commit;` to the SQL file content since `autocommit` is turned off.

The problem is, sometimes all the MySQL processes for restoring dumps hang at a random time.

I use a ramdisk by the way.

my.cnf is:

```
[mysqld]

autocommit=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G

max_allowed_packet=256M

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

innodb_log_file_size = 256M

innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

innodb_use_native_aio = 0

tmpdir=/mnt/ramdisk

datadir=/mnt/ramdisk/mysql

socket=/mnt/ramdisk/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: Could your RAM disk be full? That'd easily affect all threads at once.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason since I have more than 200 GB of RAM and 160GB used for ramdisk and the problem may happen when only about 10GB is written to the ramdisk.